# C++ interface for matplotlib

Tags: c++, binding, interface, matplotlib

I was wondering if there's an interface to matplotlib that can be used from C++.  (Perhaps something similar to what gnuplot has)

Comment: There is a solution to this problem available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c Hope this helps.

Comment: This link is dead. (Question was removed)

Answer (score 10):

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c), you can use strings:

For static data, it's really easy:

```
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
   Py_Initialize();
   PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");
   PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.plot(range(5))");
   PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.show()");
   Py_Exit(0);
   return 0;
}
```

It gets a bit more tricky, but still possible with variable data, just concatenate it to a string.

```
#include <string>
#include "Python.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Py_Initialize();
   int x[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
   int y[5] = {5, 1, 7, 5, 1};
   string command = "pylab.plot([";
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       command += x[i];
       command += ", ";
   }
   command += x[4];
   command += "], [";
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       command += y[i];
       command += ", ";
   }
   command += y[4];
   command += "])";
   PyRun_SimpleString("import pylab");
   PyRun_SimpleString(command.c_str());
   PyRun_SimpleString("pylab.show()");
   Py_Exit(0);
   return 0;
}
```

(Please note that I didn't check this for bugs, so there may be some in there, but you get the idea, and yes, it's a very ugly solution).

Comment: @Leif: That is a nice answer +1 for that, however, i believe it will not scale, if my value list is say a couple of thousand it will work fine, however if its millions of points that maybe a little different. i was really hoping there would be native bindings, like a header or some such one could call that would call the underlying matplotlib routines, as they're pretty much all written in c and c++ and get called in python, calling them the way you show it would be like this: c++->python->c++

Comment: Yes, I bet matplotlib was made with C++.  But it's entirely possible that it was built specifically around the python/c api, and not made very modular (you can check out the source to find out).  If this is the case, I'm not entirely surprised that it requires python.  Another thing you could try to do is to try to talk to matplotlib using the python/c api directly, rather than using strings.  Although I wouldn't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It is old question, but there is C++ api to use Mathplot: [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) developed from 2014